# Have function return request data + a function to execute

Tags: javascript

I have a function which gets a html file and displays it on the page but i want to tell it to also execute a function once the page has been dealt with. Except i don't know how to pass the data with it.

This is what i currently have:

```
call_file('index.html', function(){ 
                        template_handler(
                            function(){ init_menu(); }
                        )}
    );
}
```

This is handled like this:

```
function call_file(url,func){
    caller(url,function(){
        if ( xmlhttp.readyState== 4 && xmlhttp.status== 200 ){
            call_back_fileLoad(xmlhttp.responseText,func);
        }
    });
}
function call_back_fileLoad(result,func){

        if(typeof(func) !== 'undefined'){       
            func(result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}

function caller(url,cfunc){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The problem is i don't know how to receive the html & the function i want to execute at the same time as it only returns one piece of data to the function.

This is how i wish the final function to act:

```
function template_handler(data, func){
    var d = document.getElementById('content');
        d.innerHTML = '';
    var div = document.createElement(div);
        div.innerHTML = data;

    d.appendChild(div);

    func(); 
}
```

Currently i don't know how to pass the data correctly for `call_file`, please help ^_^

Comment: Don't name your functions `caller`. It will be impossible to call outside of global context.

Comment: Just define a parameter to the callback function you're passing to `call_file()`, and then pass that parameter as the first argument to `template_handler()`. Like this: `call_file('index.html', function(data){ template_handler(data, function(){ init_menu(); })});}`

Comment: @CrazyTrain not sure i understand? Do i have to change any thing on my request functions?

Comment: @sabof it works with that name though =/

Comment: @Dave: I added an example to my comment. The callback passed to `call_file` becomes `function(data) {...`, and the invocation of `template_handler` becomes `template_handler(data, function() { init...`

Comment: @Dave I don't know which browsers current have it (Chrome does), but `caller` gets locally set to the function that called the current function.

Comment: @sabof: You're saying a local variable named `caller` appears inside a function?

Comment: @sabof i don't understand what you are referring to theres nothing wrong naming a function `caller` from what i see ? And im using Chrome

Comment: @CrazyTrain do you want to post your answer as your solution worked :)

Comment: @Dave: Sure, I'll post it.

Comment: My bad regarding the `caller`, I've made an error while testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment above:

*"Just define a parameter to the callback function you're passing to `call_file()`, and then pass that parameter as the first argument to `template_handler()`. Like this:*"

```
// `call_back_fileLoad()` passes the response, so receive it here
// --------------------------------v
call_file('index.html', function(data) {
    // Then pass it on to the `template_handler()` invocation
    // ----------------v
    template_handler(data, function() { 
        init_menu(); 
    });
});
```

---

And BTW, you can probably get rid of the innermost anonymous function, and just pass `init_menu` since it appears as though it doesn't require arguments.

```
call_file('index.html', function(data){ 
    template_handler(data, init_menu);
});
```

Comment: Ok the latter works to0 :) which makes it nice and simple! Thank you!

Comment: @Dave: Let's move the discussion here. Are you making several requests, or just one? Is `call_file` being invoked multiple times?

Comment: It calls once but some times when i refresh it only does one 1 other time 5 =/

Comment: It does seem like you're using a shared variable for `xmlhttp`. I wonder if this plays some role. Go to the callback function that you're passing to `caller`, and change the 3 `xmlhttp` variables to `this` instead. So `if ( this.readyState== 4 && ...` and so on.

Comment: i solved it ! It was a complicated problem with how i set up the initial loading page. My bad! :P

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about

#### Edit

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (function(xmlhttp, url, somevar1, somevar2){
    return function() {
        cfunc.call(this, xmlhttp, url, somevar1, somevar2);
    }
})(xmlhttp, url, somevar1, somevar2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't i have to alter my `call_file` function for that

Comment: nope..? Since this implementation is in the subsequent function which will be called later. Am i missing anything..

Comment: @CrazyTrain `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;` this will be called 5 times in a successful request and my next function is taking care of the latter part `if ( xmlhttp.readyState== 4 && xmlhttp.status== 200 ){`

Comment: Sure if you were doing `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;`, it would be called multiple times, and would filter based on the `.readyState`, but that's not what you're doing. You're invoking the function as soon as it's passed to `caller()`.

Comment: Edited, does this make sense? Not even sure if it would work.  Just a wild attempt

Comment: A few problems. There's no need for the immediately invoked function; I don't know where `somevar1` and `somevar2` are coming from; Not sure why you're passing the `url`; the `cfunc` isn't set up to receive those arguments; Even if the `cfunc` was set to receive the arguments, we're still left with the original issue that OP had. Nothing has changed there.

Comment: @CrazyTrain i just noticed it is calling it a few times =/ is that suppose to happen ?

Comment: @Dave Are you asking about Atif's answer or my answer? And which function is being invoked several times? The handler assigned to `onreadystatechange` will be invoked multiple times, but the call to `call_back_fileLoad()` should be constrained by the `if` statement, and only invoked once.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yours but i couldn't tag your name in my comment. `template_handler` calls more than once which is odd.